# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: / Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, and am modeling users. User_spec.rb test is failing, and my read of the error is that for some reason the attributes aren't being read as accessible, though the code says they should be.  I've done rake db:test:prepare as well.  Any help would be appreciated greatly.

User model is straightforward.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

end
```

Test at spec/models/user_spec.rb is this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

    before { @user = User.new(user: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }

    subject { @user }

    it { should respond_to(:name) }
    it { should respond_to(:email) }

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `name` not `user`... Please check the following

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
end
```

You are making mistake while creating a new record with `Example User` for `user`. It should be `name`.

Comment: I'd love to give you an upvote, but lack the reputation to do so! :(

Comment: Vinay--i'd give you a good answer and reco.  stack overflow requires that i have a reputation of 15 before it accepts my selection.  sadly i'm at reputation 2. :(

Comment: Thanks @Vinay!  That did the trick, I can now upvote!  Many thx!

Answer (score 2):

Anything you want to update via mass-assignment needs to be in your `attr_accessible`.

Change this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

end
```

to this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :user

end
```

Although `user` doesn't seem like the right attribute name. Is it maybe supposed to be `username`?

Comment: He don't want to add new `attr_accessible` for the `:user`. Because he is wrongly put `user` instead of `name` when creating new record.